# How to Make OG image for wordpress

Tags: php, html

how to make og:image for wordrpress? this my code

```
<meta name="og:image" content="<?php
    // if home page og image
    $ogImage="https://www.example.com/test.jpg"
    if (is_home()) {echo $ogImage;}
    // if single page og image
    elseif (is_single() || is_page()) {
        $ogImage = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'og_image', true);}
    else{echo $ogImage;}
?>" />
```

but not working and my website get whitescreen. please help me. thank you

Comment: you are not echo-ing anything in the elseif part of the code, only assigning a value.

Answer (score 0):

You forget add `;` at the end `$ogImage`:

```
<meta name="og:image" content="<?php
    // if home page og image
    $ogImage="https://www.example.com/test.jpg"; // edit here
    if (is_home()) {echo $ogImage;}
    // if single page og image
    elseif (is_single() || is_page()) {
        $ogImage = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'og_image', true);}
    else{echo $ogImage;}
?>" />
```

Hope it's help you.

Comment: hello thank you @Dmitry about your answer, i appreciate it. you correct about add ";" the whitescreen not showing again. But why og:image blank <meta name="og:image" content="" />  when i viewsource the article? that must have https://www.example.com/test.jpg when im not create the "og_image" in article pos custom segment. is my code wrong?